# JS URL persistence to create templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, persistence

I have an interactive UI of elements, and I was encouraged to use divs and spans exclusively, and avoid checkboxes.  I have converted the site over to the same functionality, but don't know much about persistence to begin with, but with checkboxes, it seemed approachable given the idea of being 'checked' or 'not checked'.   How would I begin to use this approach with tracking each element's visibility?

[Here](http://specialorange.org/resume) is the page I am trying to implement persistence on.

Previous implementation (not my code, as I am new to JS and persistence) used the following:

```
// Persistence
//¿¿??
var formvals = {};
var keyval = location.search.replace('?', '').split('&');
$.each(keyval, function () {
    var splitval = this.split('=');
    formvals[splitval[0]] = splitval[1];
});

$.each($('form')[0].elements, function () {
    var key = $(this).attr('name');
    if (key && formvals[key]) {
        $('#' + key).val(formvals[key]);
    } else {
        if ($(this).attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
          $('#'+key)[0].checked = false;
        }
    }
});
```

I would like to know how to use the visibility of the elements to help develop different templates.

I can't find any intros into URL persistence, and Im not quite sure what the previous code does,  so any explanation or guidance is greatly appreciated.

If you need more information, please ask, and hopefully you can help send me down the right path.

Comment: This script takes parameters from the $_GET-string (part of an URL starting at `?`), searches elements with same names as the keys of $_GET parameters in a first `<form>`-tag and fills values in these parameters (or check checkboxes)

Comment: Visibility of what elements do you want to track?

Comment: the headings ('heading') or subsections ('element'). This would be easiest (im assuming) by referencing the left side with class 'gc' (generated content), as the right side ('form') subsections can be hidden if all elements of a section are hidden.

Comment: So I would manually write the URL? 

-and then this function would 'parse' the url, and then the second function does the work?

I was kind of thinking, from other implementations that I have seen on the web, that the url would be generated upon the state of the elements, that is why im getting confused with the code.

Comment: There is no `input`, `checkbox` or `radio` elements in your first `<form>` (top-right block) and this script will do nothing

Comment: I am new to CP altogether.  I switched the entire page from checkboxes to labels (at the advice of someone).  The persistence code shown was not written by me, and I have not found any information on how to approach persistence using the URL.   The interaction currently operates by labels and toggling the appropriate section or div.  There are no longer any `checkbox`, `radio`, or `input` elements, only `label`s, who have classes 'btn' so that it can be clicked, 'gc' or 'fs' to signify left or right side, and 'heading' or 'element' to signify header or subsection.  Your 1st comment is helping.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14670/discussion-between-chris-frisina-and-kir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If URL will be like `http://site.com/page.html?id_block_to_click1=1&id_block_to_click2=1` it should work

```
$(function(){
    var formvals = {};
    var keyval = location.search.replace('?', '').split('&');

    $.each(keyval, function () {
        var splitval = this.split('=');
        formvals[splitval[0]] = splitval[1];
    });

    $.each(formvals, function(key,val){
        if (val == 1) {
            $('#'+key).click();
        }
    })
});
```